# Responsive height for div element

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for a responsive banner

```
.mybanner { 
     height:320px; 
     background:url(../img/banner.png) no-repeat;  
     background-size:100%;
}
```

responsive image background works fine, the only problem is `.mybanner` container's height is not changing

for example when i test with big screen

```
mybanner div element width = 980px
mybanner div element height = 320px
bakcground_image width = 980px
background_image height = 320px
```

but when i resized screen, let say width mybanner div element become 680px

```
mybanner div element width = 680px
mybanner div element height = 320px
bakcground_image width = 680px
background_image height = 220px
```

from that example there is different value mybannder height with background_image height, so it's become ugly white space

I already tried to modify it like this, to make .mybanner height became auto

```
 .mybanner { 
     min-height:170px;
     max-height:320px; 
     background:url(../img/banner.png) no-repeat;  
     background-size:100%;
}
```

or this:

```
.mybanner { 
     height:100%; 
     //height:auto;
     background:url(../img/banner.png) no-repeat;  
     background-size:100%;
}
```

but not work....
any idea how to make height of div .mybanner change too depending on image size on his background

Comment: I understand English is not your language, but it's difficult to understand what you mean, probably because we don't know what .mybanner class is. Is that an image? a div? a p? something else? Remember to ALWAYS add your markup, because your height is changing. What you see (or don't see) is a completely different story, and it's based in the markup. By the way, if I had to bet, I'd suggest to change `background-size` from `100%` to `cover`

Comment: @fabio sory if i describe it not clear.....mybanner is a div element, i use 'background-size=100%' because i want to resize my background image in .mybanner according to screen.....if i used 'background-size:cover' not a whole image will be display, when screen small...my case need full image to display so i choice 100% instead of cover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to change height.

```
<body onresize="resizediv()">
<div class="mybanner" id="mybanner">
...

<script>
function resizediv() {
div = document.getElementById('mybanner');
    var imageSrc = div.style.backgroundImage.replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2').split(',')[0];

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imageSrc;

    var width = image.width,
        height = image.height;

    div.style.height = image.height; 

}
</script>
```

Or There are all background size valid properties, you can chose best one:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain

Or simple don't use background, put the IMG to the div as a object  and set image width 100% don't edit div and image height, it will compute automatically.

Comment: hm... i think the problem not in background size properties....i can use background-size:contain as well but it's give me same result as background-size:100%, because the height of mybanner div class is 320px....if i use height of mybanner class 'auto' or '100%' that banner gone (of course because mybanner don't have height and don't have any content just background)

Comment: I underdand, that you need a height of div .mybanner depending on image size on his background, edited answer

Comment: you're right if i make IMG to div as object instead of background that will be solve...but in above that image i will put same input text so i think that not suit my case...anyway when i try to use that js code...i resize down, and mybanner gone it's seem like mybanner.div.style become 0

Comment: No its only from my head, i have no test it anywhere. Problem is in size of image, when you sersize image it resize banner. You must play with that code to fit your needs, i dont know how is your site situated.

Comment: Another problem is, that  id="mybanner" is loaded after resizediv() function is inititated, edited

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62314/discussion-between-neversaysblack-and-martin).